# issue while adding user in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

whenever I try to create a new user in the admin page i get an error. Can anyone help me fix this? this is my code

```
class ChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    disabled password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'height', 'weight', 'age', 'location')

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = ChangeForm
    model = User
    
    # password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    list_display = ['pk','username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'location', 'height', 'weight', 'age', 'user_picture']
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username','first_name',  'last_name', 'password', 'location', 'height', 'weight', 'age', 'user_picture')}),
    )
    fieldsets = add_fieldsets
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: it says 'Please correct the errors below.' but there are no errors

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't need to override the admin form for excluding a password field. Just use the `exclude` attribute of `ModelAdmin` to hide the password field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude

```py
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('password',)
```

... or `readonly_fields` for protect it from changes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

```py
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('password',)
```